# Connect to a different database in django shell

Tags: python, django, shell

How can I connect to a different database when in a Django shell?

Something like:

```
python manage.py shell --database=slave
```

I tried googling all around, but couldn't find anything useful on this.

This is what my settings looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '10.10.10.10',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 1000,
    },
    'slave':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '10.10.10.10',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 1000,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can split your settings module into submodules. For instance:

```
project/
    settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        dev.py
        prod.py
        shell.py
```

Your main/common settings are located in `project/settings/base.py`

In development, set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to `project.settings.dev`.

`project/settings/dev.py` may look like:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
```

`project/settings/shell.py` may look like:

```
from .dev import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db2',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '10.10.10.10',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 1000,
    },
}

# OR
#
# DATABASES['master'] = DATABASES['default']
# DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES['slave']
```

Then run `python manage.py shell --settings=project.settings.shell`.

---

Or, alternatively, just create a second settings module:

```
project/
    settings.py
    shell_settings.py
```

`project/shell_settings.py` would look like:

```
from .settings import *

DATABASES['master'] = DATABASES['default']
DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES['slave']
```

and run `python manage.py shell --settings=project.shell_settings`

Answer (score 11):

You could select database in your query with [`using()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) ORM's method:

```
# This will hit a model in your default DB:
Model.objects.using('default').all()

# And this will hit a model in your slave DB:
Model.objects.using('slave').all()
```

Comment: Yeah, this came up in my search, but I was planning to run a lot of queries on the slave, so was looking for a better way to do it. Another approach would have been to use a different settings file, and that  seemed slightly better idea since I might want to run this on another slave later. Wanted to check if what I was looking for was directly supported. Anyways, thanks and +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `connection` module from `django.db` to create/connect to a brand new test database.

```py
from django.db import connection
db = connection.creation.create_test_db()
```

I know it's not quite what was asked, but it's helpful and quick when testing. It will create a new test database and connect you to it. I haven't figured out how to connect to an existing database with it yet, but stay tuned.

Comment: You can use `cursor = connection.cursor()` to get a cursor to the default database.